# Changed build.gradle now can't install app delete faild internal error

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I changed my gradles compileSdkVersion from 21 to 22 and forgot about it, a day later I plugged my phone in and wanted to debug my app, after trying to install once i get this message:

> Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't  match the current version (dexopt error).
> In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

and after hitting the "ok" button i get this error:

> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.themeteam.roeikashi
> DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.themeteam.roeikashi"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

I could use some help on what to do, since I deleted all the files I could find that have a connection to my app and that doesn't seem to work.
I also changed back my compileSdkVersion to 21 which didn't work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the application manually?

Comment: You need to uninstall apk manually,, I agree with @herschel and later install again

Comment: The application does not exsit on the device

Comment: The phone is rooted and I deleted the files that exsited on the device yet the error still occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the gradle file, the compileSdkVersion was accidentally changed from 21 to 22, so I had to change it back, change the buildToolVersion and the target sdk version to the latest version.

the comments were way off, I ended up deleting all my phones cached data as my app does save some data on the phone itself and that didn't work.
It just occured to me that I should use the latest version and that fixed it.

here's the new gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.themeteam.roeikashi"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
//    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
}
```